# Working with multiple button in a FieldList Flask form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a dynamic form created using field list.

```
class GiftForm(Form):
    item = StringField('Gift Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = StringField('Gift Description')
    url = StringField('Gift URL')
    remove_gift = SubmitField("Remove Gift")


class GiftListForm(FlaskForm):
    category_name = StringField('Category')
    gifts = FieldList(FormField(GiftForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField('Proceed To Step 3')
```

I am then populating the form in HTML using a for loop (using Jinja)

Since its FieldList, all the 'remove_gift' buttons get different names like:

- gifts-0-remove_gift
- gifts-1-remove_gift
- gifts-2-remove_gift

In my app.py I generally get the name of the button that was clicked using following code:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['button_group'] == 'delete_gift':
            print("delete gift requested")
        elif request.form['button_group'] == 'add_gift':
            print("add gift requested")
```

But for above code to work, all the button should have same name 'button_group'
If the name is populated in a dynamic way (button_group_0, button_group_1) how to I check that in my app.py?